# Graph with $k$ components.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices. If $G$ has $k$ components and every component is complete prove that:
$$|E| \le \frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$$
I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Try proving this for $k=2$.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: First test the statement on some small case (say $k=1$,$n=3$) to see if it's correct. Are you sure it wasn't$$|E|\le\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}2?$$

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

If the graph has $k$ components of size $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$ then it has $\displaystyle \frac{n_1(n_1-1)}{2} + \frac{n_2(n_2-1)}{2} + \dots + \frac{n_k(n_k-1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\sum n_i^2 - n)$ edges.

Now, can you bound $\sum n_i^2$ under the constraint that $\sum n_i = n$?

Comment: Note that each $n_i$ is strictly positive.

Comment: It's great idea. But I can't finish it. Can you give more help?

Comment: The sum is maximized with $k-1$ components of size $1$ and one component of size $n-k+1$. Then, the number of edges is less than $\frac{1}{2}((k-1) + (n-k+1)^2 - n) = \frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$

Comment: How do you prove that this is how the sum is maximized ?

Comment: If $n_1 \leq n_2$ then $n_1^2 + n_2^2 < (n_1-1)^2 + (n_2+1)^2 = n_1^2 + n_2^2 + 2(n_2 - n_1) + 2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In other words, you have to prove that, if $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are positive integers such that $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$, then
$$\binom{x_1}2+\cdots+\binom{x_k}2\le\binom{n-k+1}2.$$
In other words, you want to know that the sum
$$\binom{x_1}2+\cdots+\binom{x_k}2$$
is maximized (subject to the given constraints, i.e., positive integers adding up to $n$) when $x_1=\cdots=x_{k-1}=1$ and $x_k=n-k+1$.

We may as well assume that $x_1\le\cdots\le x_k$. The problem is trivial if $k=1$, so let's say $k\ge2$. Now, supposing $x_1\gt1$, what happens to the sum if we change $x_1$ to $x_1-1$ and $x_k$ to $x_k+1$? Does it get bigger or smaller?