# Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $k$ connected components, show that the maximum number of edges is ${n - k + 1 \choose 2} $

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory

I am trying to prove the question I wrote in the title. I realized that the maximum number of edges is the maximal value of $ {a_1\choose 2} + ... + {a_k \choose 2}$ such that $a_i \geq 1$ for all $i$ and $a_1+...+a_k = n$. 
 But now I don't know how to prove that the value of this is the needed one. I know it is reached when all of the $a_i$'s are $1$ except one which is $n-k+1$ but I don't know how to prove this is the maximal case. I have tried induction but it just got to messy.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049122/graph-with-k-components

Answer (score 2):

What happens to the number of edges when one point is moved from a small group to a larger group ?  So replace $a_1,a_2$ with $a_1-1,a_2+1$.

Comment: Okay I understood know why every case that is not the case I mentioned cannot be the maximal one: we can take two weights that are not 1, and move one point from the smaller group to the larger one. but what do I do if all the weights are equal?

Comment: Compare $a_1,a_1$ with $a_1-1,a_1+1$

Answer (score 0):

Since the graph has k connected componenets, let each of them have n<sub>i</sub> vertices  ∀ i ∈ [1, k]
Also  Σn<sub>i</sub> = n
Max Edges in each component having n<sub>i</sub> vertices = **(n<sub>i</sub>)(n<sub>i</sub> -1)/2**
so Total edges in k components , let say E will be as given below:

E = Σ(n<sub>i</sub>)(n<sub>i</sub> - 1) / 2

**E = (Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) - n) / 2**  Lets consider this equation 1
Now since we know that
Σ(n<sub>i</sub>) = n 
Σ(n<sub>i</sub> - 1) = n - k (On Subtracting k from both sides)

(Σ(n<sub>i</sub> - 1))<sup>2</sup> = (n - k)<sup>2</sup> (On squaring both sides)

Σ(n<sub>i</sub> - 1)<sup>2</sup> + Other Positive Terms = (n - k)<sup>2</sup>

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + 1 - 2n<sub>i</sub>) + C = n<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup> - 2nk

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + k - 2n + C = n<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup> - 2nk

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + C = n<sup>2</sup> + k<sup>2</sup> - 2nk + 2n - k

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + C = n<sup>2</sup> -k(2n - k) + 1(2n - k)

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + C = n<sup>2</sup> + (1 - k)(2n - k)

Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) + C = n<sup>2</sup> - (k - 1)(2n - k)
**Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) ≤ n<sup>2</sup> - (k - 1)(2n - k) as C > 0**

 After plugging this result into equation 1
and simpifying we get:-

E = (Σ(n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) - n) / 2 ≤ (n<sup>2</sup> - (k - 1)(2n - k) - n)/2

On Simplyfing, we get 

E ≤ ( (n - k)<sup>2</sup> + (n - k) )/2

 **E ≤ (n - k)(n - k + 1)/2**